# Alternative JSF implementation with JBoss 71

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, icefaces

I am trying to use icefaces 1.7.1 in a war application deployed on JBoss 7.0.0.Final

Deployment is failing with an error "Could not compile stylesheet" in icefaces-comp.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  I assume this is because JBoss 7 is expecting me to use the JSF implementation that comes with JBoss 7.

I can not change or upgrade the JSF implementation.

JBoss 6 allowed legacy applications to add the following to web.xml so that the JSF implementation bundled with JBoss is ignored:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This does not seem to work with JBoss 7.

Does anybody know how to use an alternative JSF implementation with JBoss 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JBoss 7.0.1.Final has been released and fixes this issue, i.e. the org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL context param now works in JBoss 7.0.1.Final.